# Приложение - сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, android

Здравствуйте.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать приложение-демонстрацию сайта. По сути, это оффлайн сайт, в виде приложения.
Есть полностью скаченный сайт. Содержит он не только HTML, но и различные скрипты *.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, методику встраивания сайта в приложение.

Comment: PhoneGap(DroidGap)    
или обычный WebView

Comment: PhoneGap я еще никогда не пользовался. Я больше нацелен на WebView.
Меня больше интересуют такие вопросы:
1) Куда деть сам сайт? У меня он есть полностью скаченный, размер 14 Мб.
2) Переходы по ссылкам между страничками.

Comment: 1) Положить на пример в assets/www
2) Сайт скорее всего с относительными ссылками...     
Проверьте, если работает на компе без интернета переход по все ссылкам, то будет работать и на телефоне.    
    
Предполагаю, что интересует, как в WebView открыть index.html. Тут нам гугл поможет. Запрос  в гугл: WebView android open html from assets

Comment: На компе все работает отлично.
Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Спасибо, именно это мне и было нужно! Все работает, и оказалось гораздо проще, чем я предполагал!

Answer (score 1):

[Building Web Apps in WebView.](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Прямо совсем сделать офлайн приложение можно на Cordova в таком случае:

- Если ваш файл работает на локалке нормально, то можете в blank project просто поместить всю папку с сайтом и сделать сборку.